# Devise com usuário pai e usuário filho

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Eu tenho isso na minha *Classe* `User` no devise

```
class User
     belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'User'
     has_many :children, :class_name => 'User'
     ...
    end
```

o que gostaria de saber é como ficaria a `migration` de `User` num caso como esse?

Comment: Márcio, em off, posso te dar uma dica? Não use o Devise, ele é meio ilusório - não é tão milagroso assim e você vai ter esses pequenos contratempos por causa de suas particularidades. Se você quiser entender um pouco melhor, no meu blog eu criei [um post](http://oderdenge.com/devise-e-quase-uma-cilada/) justamente sobre isso.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Achei muito interessante o teu post. Já fiz uma aplicação com autenticação *from scratch* e estou testando o Devise numa que estou desenvolvendo atualmente. Minha dúvida aqui é se vale a pena "desinstalar" o Devise agora ou se deixo assim mesmo. =)

Comment: Olá, @user3153542 (tá na hora de mudar de nick, ein? hahaha). Rapaz, na minha opinião, se já tens pronto e *não estás te incomodando*, então mantém assim. Se estiveres com alguns problemas, então vou te contar uma história... Já usei Devise em uma aplicação minha e ele estava lá, estável e *operandis*. Certo dia, precisei injetar alguma complexidade e ele só me deu problemas. Pensei assim: *Quer saber? Que se dane!* Passei uma borracha no que fizera até então e refiz do zero.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Troquei o nick =). Quanto a aplicação, vou manter o Devise mesmo.

Comment: Agora sim, @Andrey!

Comment: Interessante seu post @GuilhermeOderdenge. Como minha aplicação tera uma certa complexidade, vou seguir sua dica e criar auth a partir do zero e melhorar conforme a demanda e a segurança pedir, muito obrigado pela interação! :)

Answer (score 2):

Não testei na prática, mas tente o seguinte.

Uma vez criado o modelo via gerador do Devise, crie um migration com o seguinte:

```
def change
  change_table(:users) do |t|
    t.references :parent, index: true
  end
end
```

Então faça:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, class_name: 'User',
                      foreign_key: 'parent_id'

  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Não deixe de conferir [esta seção do guia oficial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins).